# How to introduce custom hot keys for the styles of cells?

Tags: front-end, document-creation

In the JournalArticle StyleSheet there are useful hot keys Alt+6 for a DisplayFormulaNumbered and Alt+5 for the DisplayFormula. Such hot keys, however, are not present in the Default StyleSheet. Even more, there Alt+5 is reserved for the Section, and Alt+6 - for the subsection styles.

Is it possible to introduce custom hot keys for (generally) any cell style for which there is no built-in one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more details the short answer is that you need to add e.g. `MenuCommandKey->"7"` to a style to use that key for a style.

Comment: Thank you. So, there is no way without the necessity of changing the StyleSheet?

Comment: Not that I know of

Comment: Mike in the combination you have shown above the key combination Alt+7 is created. It it possible to fix also Ctrl+something or Ctrl+Shift+something using this approach?

Comment: Not that I know of but have not investigated this before.